# How is "<scrscriptipt>" or "selselectect" used to avoid filtering?

Tags: web-application, attack-prevention

A technique for avoid filtering of common words is the one I described in the title.

However, why does this technique work? SELECT isn't the same as SELSELECTECT for example.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Let's say I blacklisted the word `<script>` and replace it with nothing.  Then `<scr<script>ipt>` becomes `<script>`.

This is why well-written html sanitizers/purifiers apply the rules recursively.  That is only when the last sanitation step made no changes to the content will it stop/not apply another round of the processing rules.  (It also likely will fail and return no content if too many processing rounds are necessary).

Comment: IMO a well written html doesn't use such replacement rules in the first place. It should actually parse the html into a DOM like representation, and then generate output form it after comparing tags/attributes against a whitelist.

Comment: @CodesInChaos - Agree.  I'm not advocating someone builds their own HTML sanitizer.  Its saner to just use a safe lightweight markup language (where symbols like `<` are automatically escaped to `&lt;` and whitelisted safe HTML elements are inserted) or well-tested HTML purifier, [and have said](http://security.stackexchange.com/a/30435/2568) this [more than once](http://security.stackexchange.com/a/18560/2568).  However, this is a clear example of bypassing non-recursive filtering (see [example 5](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_Reflected_Cross_site_scripting_\(OWASP-DV-001\)) ).

Comment: The question is if a more paranoid sanitizer shouldn't simply return nothing or an error condition whenever it even *finds* bad words instead of trying to make something sensible out of from an apparent attack.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen - For HTML sanitation there is a good solution of just escaping `<>&'"` to their HTML escaped versions e.g., `&lt;` that the browser specifically should not invoke, and just because you saw `<scr<script>>` doesn't necessarily imply an attack -- it could be a generic discussion like what we are having where someone forgot to escape.  Granted, I agree with your approach to sanitation if you are sure its an attack of some sort.  E.g., if a POST variable came from a pull down form and there's an unexpected value -- that could mean someone's attacking/probing you.

Answer (score 13):

This works against broken sanitizers that simply use `s.Replace("select","")`. When you apply that to `selselectect`, it removes the `select` in the middle, but since it doesn't run again on the output, the split `sel`+`ect` becomes `select` and survives the sanitizer.

This attack won't work against any sane sanitizer.